# Can I do an SQL query on a table and its join table at the same time?

Tags: sql, join

I have a couple tables that look like this:

```
 ___________    ___________
| Books     |  | Tags      |
|-----------|  |-----------|
| book_id   |  | tag_id    |
| book_name |  | tag_name  |
 -----------    -----------
```

And a join table that connects the "many-to-many relationship":

```
 ___________
| Books/Tags|
|-----------|
| book_id   |
| tag_id    |
 -----------
```

I have the following query:

```
SELECT book_name, tag_name FROM books 
JOIN books_tags ON books.book_id = books_tags.book_id 
JOIN tags ON tags.tag_id = books_tags.tag_id 
WHERE books.book_id = 283
```

And the following (for books that aren't tagged):

```
SELECT book_name FROM books WHERE books.book_id = 283
```

Is there a way to merge those two queries into one?

Comment: what do u mean by merging two queries ? what are you looking for actually ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want a LEFT join

```
SELECT book_name, 
       tag_name 
FROM   books 
       LEFT JOIN books_tags 
         ON books.book_id = books_tags.book_id 
       LEFT JOIN tags 
         ON tags.tag_id = books_tags.tag_id 
WHERE  books.book_id = 283
```

Answer (score 0):

Do your first query but use a `LEFT JOIN` for the first join clause. A left join in this case gives you all records from the books table, regardless of matches, along with matching rows that *are* joined.

Answer (score 0):

you could (thanks for the comment!) use union . I am not sure what you mean with " merge those two queries into one "

> SELECT book_name, tag_name FROM books 
>   JOIN books_tags ON books.book_id =
>   books_tags.book_id  JOIN tags ON
>   tags.tag_id = books_tags.tag_id  WHERE
>   books.book_id = 283
>
> UNION
>
> SELECT book_name,'' FROM books WHERE
>   books.book_id = 283

Comment: "could", not "should" -- a UNION means two passes over the BOOKS table, but what the OP wants can be done in one using an OUTER JOIN.

Comment: thanks for the comment. and you are right the outer also solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use LEFT JOIN instead of jOIN to merge both queries.

Take a look at [this documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp).